# Solving system of two dependent linear congruence equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, chinese-remainder-theorem

$$23d \equiv 1 \pmod{40}$$
$$73d \equiv 1 \pmod{102}$$

How can I solve this? $40$ and $102$ are not coprime, so I figured I can factor the moduli:

$$23d \equiv 25 \pmod 8$$
$$23d \equiv 26 \pmod 5$$
$$73d \equiv 25 \pmod 2$$
$$73d \equiv 25 \pmod 3$$
$$73d \equiv 18 \pmod{17}$$

---

All right, now - if I have both $23d \equiv 25 \pmod 8$ and the $23d \equiv 25 \pmod 2$, can I throw the first one out?

---

If so, I later have:

$$23d \equiv 26 \pmod 5$$
$$73d \equiv 25 \pmod 2$$
$$73d \equiv 25 \pmod 3$$
$$73d \equiv 18 \pmod{17}$$

---

What should I do next if I wanna use Chinese reminder theorem to solve this? I mean, how can I get rid of the $23$ and $73$?

For example, let's take $23d \equiv 26 \pmod 5$. I'd have to add $5$ to $26$ until I get the number that $23$ is divisible by. Is there a way to evaluate this quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you express your congruences is rather unconventional. Given that
$$23d\equiv1\pmod{40},$$
$$73d\equiv1\pmod{102},$$
and that $40=2^3\times5$ and $102=2\times3\times17$, it follows that
$$23d\equiv1\pmod5,$$
$$23d\equiv1\pmod8,$$
$$73d\equiv1\pmod2,$$
$$73d\equiv1\pmod3,$$
$$73d\equiv1\pmod{17}.$$
It is common practice to express a congruence like $23d\equiv25\pmod8$ as $23d\equiv1\pmod8$, or even $-d\equiv1\pmod8$. It makes the modular arithmetic easier to do by heart.

Each of these congruences can further be reduced. For the first, note that
$$23d\equiv3d\pmod5,$$
and that $3d\equiv1\pmod5$ implies $d\equiv2\pmod5$. You can do the same for the other moduli, and then use the Chinese remainder theorem to find all possible values of $d$.

As for your remark; if you have $23d\equiv25\pmod8$ then it follows that $23d\equiv25\pmod2$, but not conversely. So you *cannot* throw the first one out, but you *can* throw the second one out.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it now. I just don't see how $23d \equiv 1 (mod 8)$ implies $3d \equiv 1 (mod 8)$.

Comment: It's a typo, fixed it now.

Comment: I changed (\operatorname{mod} 3) to \pmod 3 and (\operatorname{mod}17) to \pmod{17}, etc.  The standard notation provides proper spacing to its left and right and also between "mod" and the number that follows it.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Thank you. I always dreamt of such a command existing. Now I know it does.